# Правильный расчет комбинации стрит

Tags: python, python-3.x

Столкнулся с проблемой а именно подходом в расчете, в `faces` у меня есть не только цифры, но и их последовательность нужно учитывать, моя функция рассчитывает стрит только циферных карт до 10. Но J, Q, K, A уже не проходят проверку как можно переделать так чтобы это работало вместе с буквами?

```
suits = "♥,♠,♣,♦".split(',')
faces = "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K,A"
face = faces.split(',')

class Card(namedtuple('Card', 'face, suit')):
    def __repr__(self):
        return ''.join(self)

hand = [Card("2", "♥"),Card("10", "♥"),Card("9", "♥"),Card("8", "♥"),Card("J", "♥"),Card("Q", "♥")]

#Проверка на стрит
def straight(hand):
    ordered = sorted(hand, key=lambda card: (faces.index(card.face), card.suit))
    if ''.join(card.face for card in ordered) in ''.join(face):
        return 5, f"Стрит до {ordered[-1].face}"
    return False;
```

Comment: Как вариант можно картам начиная с вальта присвоить числовые значения, типа 11, 12 и так далее, а потом конвертировать обратно

Comment: Попробую сделать словарь `faces = {"two": 2 ... "ace": 14}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import collections
import operator
from enum import IntEnum



Suits = IntEnum("Suits", "♥ ♠ ♣ ♦")
Ranks = IntEnum("Ranks", "A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K")
Card = collections.namedtuple("Card", "rank suit")

cardsinfo = [(3, "♣"), (4, "♦"), (5, "♥"), (6, '♥'), (7,'♥')]
hand = [Card(Ranks(r), Suits[s]) for r,s in cardsinfo]

def straight(hand):
    hand.sort(key=operator.attrgetter("rank"))

    start = hand[0].rank
    straight = [Card(r, None) for r in range(start, start+6)]
    if all(got.rank == want.rank for got,want in zip(hand, straight)):
        print(f"Стрит до {hand[-1].rank}")
    else: print('Увы, в следующий раз полюбому будет стрит')
```

Comment: и снова вы тут мой спаситель) Спасибо еще раз)

Comment: Где можно научиться использовать collections, enum, operator и all?